# Preserving the order of annotations

Tags: java, android, annotations

When obtaining the list of fields using `getFields()` and `getDeclaredFields()`, the order of the fields in a `Java class` is undefined.

I need this order in my validation library. Since the order is not preserved (though some claim that the order is preserved in JDK 6 and above but is not guaranteed across VMs). I cannot speculate on this because the order of annotations across fields is absolutely essential for the library.

One way to get around this is to have an `order` or an `index` attribute in my `Annotation`.

What worries me is that the code could become a bit cumbersome for maintaining in the following case.

1. If the use wants to insert a new annotated field then, he might have to renumber all the other annotations in the class.
2. I could have the `order` or `index` as a floating point number - `float` or `double` but , it wouldn't look good to have order such as 1, 1.5, 2, etc.,

What would be an elegant solution for this problem?

Here is a example code so that you can get an idea about the problem:

```
@Required
@TextRule (minLength = 6, message = "You need at least 6 characters.")
private EditText usernameEditText;

@Password
private EditText passwordEditText;

@ConfirmPassword
private EditText confirmPasswordEditText;

@Email
private EditText emailEditText;
```

Comment: What is wrong by ordering the names as Strings? Seems like the natural ordering to me (if you change the name you are changing the method).

Comment: @SJuan76 please check the code above, String ordering wouldn't be an option. Seems the Dalvik VM orders fields by their names. So the order of the annotations is also not preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no means to achieve this. Because until Java 5, the order of the declared fields is undefined. In Java 6 and up the order is preserved. And the Dalvik VM on the other hand sorts the field names according to their names in Ascending order. Finally I solved this problem by adding the order `attribute` to my annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the ordering is not inherent to the class itself, but depends of the class using it. So I would consider forgetting about modifying the original class and add a `properties` file (probably with the same name of the class) to define the order.

If you need to add items later, just don't step the ordering 1 by 1 but (say) 10 by 10. First method has index 1, second method has index 11, and so on. It will be improbable that you need to reindex that, and, if you do, reindex the properties file is easily done by hand/program.

Comment: I am writing a framework that uses annotations to validate UI widgets, so my class uses Annotations declared on other classes.